# Lambda capture [*this] in class get segment fault

Tags: c++, lambda

In C++20, `[*this]` was allowed. So I tried following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    int x = 5;
    function<int(int)>fun = [*this](int y) mutable
    {
        return x;
    };
};
int main() {
    int x;
    A a{};
    cout<<a.fun(3)<<endl;
    cout<<a.x<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to capture `[*this]` in class but got segmentation fault; however, the following methods are possible.

```
class A
{
    int x = 5;
    function<int(int)>fun = [this](int y)
    {
        return this->x + y;
    };
};

class A
{
    int x = 5;
    function<int(int)>fun = [=](int y)
    {
        return this->x + y;
    };
};

class A
{
    int x = 5;
    function<int(int)>fun = [&](int y)
    {
        return this->x + y;
    };
};
```

Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: Are you familiar with how copying works in C++?

Comment: FYI, capturing `*this` was added in C++17, not C++20

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making a copy of an unitialized `std::function` object.

When an `A` object is constructed, it needs to make a copy of itself for the lambda that will be used to initialize `fun` to capture.  That copy needs to copy `fun`, but `fun` hasn't been initialized yet, and so attempting to make a copy of it results in undefined behavior.

---

Your other examples are fine, because none of them make a copy of `*this`, and therefore never try to copy its uninitialized `fun` member.